# Open visio file and prompt Saveas window

Tags: c#, visio

I have visio file which I want to open in visio and prompt save as window automatically that means I want to open visio file through my C# code and want to prompt save as window which is normally open by pressing F12 button. Problem with me is that I successfully open visio file but stuck on how to prompt save as window by auto pressing F12 through my code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

document.Application.DoCmd(visCmdFileSaveAs) ?